# jenkins Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli)

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

```
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO]   ignoring changes on: **/pom.xml.backup, **/release.properties, **/pom.xml.branch, **/pom.xml.next, **/pom.xml.releaseBackup, **/pom.xml.tag
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /opt/Jenkins/ic/jenkins/jobs/util/workspace && git status
[INFO] Working directory: /opt/Jenkins/ic/jenkins/jobs/util/workspace
[INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
[INFO] Transforming 'my_proyect'...
[INFO] Not generating release POMs
[INFO] Executing goals 'clean verify'...

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:23.375s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 22 15:21:16 ECT 2014
[JENKINS] Archiving /opt/Jenkins/ic/jenkins/jobs/util/workspace/pom.xml to xx.xxx.xxxx/my_proyect/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/my_proyect-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/246M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) on project my_proyect: Could not create temporary file for release settings.xml: Permission denied -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

I need help.
When built a snapshot does not give me problems, but if I want to generate a release I get the above log.
I have the jenkins 1.548
maven 3.1.1
nexus 2.7.0-0

Comment: Your error : "Could not create temporary file for release settings.xml: Permission denied ". So check your rights !

Comment: Look I gave him permission to file settings.xml maven and maven user tomcat runs as well as the other tools.
Any other ideas ..

Comment: Do you still have this issue? If so, I think that I have the solution for you.

Comment: @jedison, what is your solution? I have similar problem (will post it soon in SO)

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins + maven-release-plugin + settings.xml = painful

Check the following locations for any mention or overrides of settings.xml file:

- Jenkins

  - instance-level config

    - general Maven section
    - Maven release plugin section
  - job-level config

    - general Maven section
    - Maven release plugin section
- pom.xml file

  - maven-release-plugin section
  - profiles section

In addition, things can get fussy depending on how you're running the job in Jenkins:

- freestyle job with Maven goals
- Maven job using regular "Build" button with "release:prepare" goals
- Maven build using "Run Maven Release" button

Try experimenting with different job types.

Comment: fixed the downvote for you. SO are replete with bulliers who do nothing but go around and downvote other people's posts.